# Expressions for living one's life

Tags: словоупотребление, узус

I've seen expressions for living one's life expressed with the accusative: **Она жила *спокойную жизнь***, as well as with the instrumental: **Пока другие люди *жили своей жизнью*...**

Is there any difference between these two usages or are they completely interchangeable?

Comment: First one is wrong, simply.

Comment: Seconded—This verb is used so randomly with accusative or instrumental—help us out, please)

Comment: Она _вела_ спокойную жизнь, per chance?

Answer (score 4):

*`Она жила спокойную жизнь` is wrong, in my opinion.  Instrumental case is needed here. You can, however, say `она`**`прожила`** `спокойную жизнь`.

Comment: Но ведь до того как она ее прожила, она ее жила?

Comment: @PavelMayorov - no.  Она жила ей (тв. падеж).

Comment: Почему? В чем разница?

Comment: По-моему, вы тролль.

Comment: По-моему, вы дали ответ без аргументации.

Comment: У меня есть мысль, и я буду ее думать. ©

Comment: К вопросу об аргументации. Во всех значениях, кроме переносного "существовать"(живёт такая идея ), "жить" – глагол непереходный. "Прожить"– переходный. So in everyday life жить should be used with the instrumental. But in fiction as a special literary device...writers are free to choose or invent their style.

Comment: @V.V. почему вы считаете глагол непереходным?

Comment: Ефремова Т.Ф. Толковый словарь русского языка.

жить
**несов. неперех**
1) а) Быть живым, существовать (о человеке или животном).
б) Расти, не вянуть (о растениях).
в) перен. Находиться, иметься (о чувствах).
2) а) Обитать, водиться где-л., населять что-л.
б) Пребывать, проживать где-л.
И т.д. там длинное продолжение.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, looking back on a life already lived, one would say "Она прожила спокойную жизнь"; yet in describing how she was living her life at any given point in the past, the instrumental would be in order "Она жила спокойной жизнью." For instance, let's say our subject was leading a peaceful life in the country, when she received news of her mother's illness in the city. The contrast  in her impending life change could be captured with: "Она жила спокойной жизнью в делевне, а теперь поняла, что ей необходимо переехать в Москву" ? (excuse any errors)

Comment: @CocoPop - yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be said "жить спокойную жизнь" - we rather say "spend" than "live" if wanna use accusative. So it'll sound as "она вела спокойную жизнь".

You should not use verb "жить" with accusative. It would sound strange (though will remain understood).

Comment: Thank you, Boticelli! We also say LEAD a (quiet) life, etc.